# Django: Collapseable menu dont stay expanded/collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, menu

I'm using Django 1.5 with Python 2.7.  I have an `ul` menu on the side with a toggle-function, shown in this picture: http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3278/d9b2xobc_jpg.htm.

So now my problem:

If I click on a link from the expanded menu, Django renders the complete site and the menu is collapsed again. Is it possible for the menu to stay expanded although the site is always newly rendered?

**Here is the html:**

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf8">
    <title>DonkeyBase</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%  static 'style.css' %}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="{%  static 'script.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="logout">
        {% if user.is_active %}angemeldet als: {{ user.username }} &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/benutzerverwaltung/logout">Logout</a>
        {% else %} <a href="/">Login</a>{% endif %}
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="{%  static 'images/DonkeyBaseEsel2_ora.png' %}" alt="logo" width="123" height="123">
        </div>
        <div id="text">
        <h1>DonkeyBase</h1>
        <h3><span id="h3">Saved by DonkeyBase!</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    <ul id="menu1" class="example_menu">
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="studie">Studien</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/studienverwaltung">Studienverwaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/studienverwaltung/createStudieForm">Studie anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/studienverwaltung/showStudie">Studien anzeigen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="operation">Operationen</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/opverwaltung">Operationsverwaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/opverwaltung/erstellenOp">Operation anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/opverwaltung/anzeigeOp">Operationen anzeigen</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="laborwert">Laborwerte</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/laborwertverwaltung">Laborwertverwaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/laborwertverwaltung/erstellenLaborwert">Laborwert anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/laborwertverwaltung/anzeigeLaborwert">Laborwerte anzeigen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="patient">Patient</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/patientenverwaltung">Patientenverwaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/patientenverwaltung/erstellenPatient">Patient anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/patientenverwaltung/anzeigePatient">Patienten anzeigen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="benutzer">Benutzer</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/benutzerverwaltung">Benutzerverwaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="/benutzerverwaltung/createUser">Benutzer anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/benutzerverwaltung/createGruppe">Gruppe erstellen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/benutzerverwaltung/showGruppe">Gruppe anzeigen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="probe">Proben</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/probenverwaltung">Probenverwaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Probe anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="/probenverwaltung/showProbe">Probe anzeigen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="collapsed" id="histo">Histologiebefunde</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Histo anlegen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Histo anzeigen</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="test" style="float: right; absolute: fixed;"></div>
        <h2>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h2>
        &nbsp;
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu1 > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded").toggleClass("collapsed").parent().find('> ul').slideToggle("fast");
        });
});
```

Comment: give display:block for ul which is sliding
Then it ll be displayed first and on clicking it toggles.

Comment: but clicking on a link will render the page without the display:block or am i thinking wrong ?

Comment: There is no href for link class="collpased/expanded".SO which page will it render

Comment: to avoid confusion u can use span instead of anchor for them

Comment: i mean the <li> elements that are links clicking on them will render the hole page again its kind of a template and it just paste the content in the content block on the bottom so alle will me rendered by clicking on an <li> element

Comment: I dont think page will render by clicking on #menu1 li a,as it does nt have any href

Comment: sure it will not but my problem is it should stay expanded after clicking on a <li> with a href or any other href